# API integration testing - is it bad practice to test Post/Put/Delete in a single test method?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing

I have been mulling on ways to end-to-end test an API call, with the likes of POST/PUT/DELETE troubling me the most.

The reason being, nunits don't run in order - and if they are asked to explicitly, they do not necessary wait for the previous test to finish. So how does one test against test data? e.g.

- Post a testdata json
- Put a testdata update
- Get the testdata
- Delete the testdata

so that by the end of my test I have not polluted my DB, and I have made sure all my endpoints provide with end to end functionality?

Between injecting the actual repository to set up and tear down DB entries, and what not, in the end I decided on:

```
 [Test]
    public void PostAndPutAndDeleteWorkWithoutErrors()
    {
        //setup
        var client = JsonClient.GetClient();
        var request = GenerateNewRequest();

        //act post
        var httpResponse = client.PostJson(uri, request );

        //assert
        httpResponse.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //act put
        httpResponse = client.PutJson(uri, request );

        //assert
        httpResponse.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //act delete
        httpResponse = client.DeleteJson(uri, request .Name);

        //assert
        httpResponse.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      }
```

Now this test tests more things than one (Post/Put/Delete), which breaks the idea of a single unit of work...
Or could one say : this does test a single unit of work - the entire cycle of posting, putting, and deleting.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Few points to better test the API endpoints. You can write logic to pick random data from target environment DB and use that data to do testing. This way you can ensure that you are doing testing on actual data and not some dummy data. Secondly, you may want to identify your critical services and focus on testing those in all respects. (Load and performance testing). This way you can ensure what will happen if one of the key services goes down.

Comment: Thank you for that :) Random data is fine , but it's the PUT/DELETE/POST that cause me problems. It's unlikely it will affect QA work, but I do not think we have scripts that run to repopulate DB nightly, weekly or at all. So if I keep deleting random data every time integration runs, soon we'll run out of data ! Every services wrapped by the API is already unit/integration tested. :)

Comment: Why don't you just put the data insertion/deletion logic into the [setup]/[teardown] method? These two run before and after each testcases are run, so then you can have isolated tests per operation.

Comment: Good point, thought about it - however insertion/deletion are tests of their own through post/delete. The way to do it like you suggest would be to instantiate the actual DB repository, and create fake data, and delete it on teardown - extra problem with the latter bit: how would we test the DELETE action then? And how could we verify that DELETE was the last test to run?. This did feel like a bit of an overkill and/or tight coupling of an external dependency that shouldn't be there when running an API series of tests! Good point though :)

Comment: I recommend you using PACTs instead of that :)

https://docs.pact.io/5-minute-getting-started-guide